# How to print a list in Google Colab without breaking lines?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory, mnist

I am trying to print one of the MNIST image in Google Colab without breaking lines. The problem is Colab break lines for each arrays in the list. Here is my code:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
mnist = fetch_openml("mnist_784", parser="pandas")

import numpy as np
print(mnist['data'].iloc[0].values.reshape(28, 28))
```

And here is the result.

[image]

I checked the settings but there are no setting for prevent breaking lines. I also used `np.array()` and for loop but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the `print` method uses the dunder method `__str__` of your object - here a numpy array - for the display of your variable, [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print). Although, there is another representation option, a lower level of representation for developer. Object also have another dunder method `__repr__`, this lower level representation can be seen with calling your object with the function `repr` which returns a `str`.

Note that if you type:

```py
>>> ar = np.arange(4)

# Display formatting by print function
>>> print(ar)
[0 1 2 3 4]
>>> str(ar)
'[0 1 2 3 4]'

# Display formatting by Python REPL
>> ar
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>> repr(ar)
'array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])'
```

So in your case if we have

```py
>>> ar = np.arange(1).reshape(5, 3)
>>> repr(ar)
'array([[ 0,  1,  2],\n       [ 3,  4,  5],\n       [ 6,  7,  8],\n       [ 9, 10, 11],\n       [12, 13, 14]])'
```

Note that using the `str` gives us a poorer representation

```py
>>> str(ar)
'[[ 0  1  2]\n [ 3  4  5]\n [ 6  7  8]\n [ 9 10 11]\n [12 13 14]]'
```

Then we want to delete the newline character and the space, so we use `replace` method of class `str`.

```py
>>> repr(ar).replace("\n      ", "")
'array([[ 0,  1,  2],[ 3,  4,  5],[ 6,  7,  8],[ 9, 10, 11],[12, 13, 14]])'
```

This is what you asked, if I understood well :)

Plus, if you want to add more dimensions to your array - here it's 2D -, maybe the method I used to "format" the `str` given by `repr` won't be that easy. You would have two options:

- Write a function to format the string as you wish
- Write a function that generate a string from a numpy array object.